# TeamCity commits changes on every save when "Versioned settings" is no

Tags: teamcity-9.1

Is there a way to tell TeamCity 9.1 to commit settings only if I explicitly ask it to?

When I turned on "Versioned settings" feature and kept fiddling with other settings TeamCity created a commit every time I clicked `Save` button.

Answer (score 1):

The description is pretty clear on what this feature does:

> On this page you can enable synchronization of the current project settings with the version control: if the project settings are changed, the affected configuration files will be checked in to the version control;
>   if the configuration files are changed in the version control, the changes will be applied to the project.

The problem with the "Versioned Settings" feature that is that it creates too darn many commits. There should be an option to add a "quiet period", like when you add a VCS checkout trigger.

Comment: I thought TeamCity is smart enough to mute triggers for commits which are just settings made in TeamCity UI.

Comment: You are correct: Commits created by the feature "Versioned Settings" do not count as VCS triggers. But that's not what I meant. I suggested that there should be a grace period, so that if you change a bunch of settings in a project they all get rolled into one big "Versioned Settings" commit.

Answer (score 0):

I tried just turning off Versioned Settings for now, then re-enabling it when I wanted to commit anything. It sort of worked, but at some point it couldn't resolve differences between the (newer) config on the server and the (older) config in VCS. So I just deleted the config from the VCS and started sync from scratch.